# ButtonStyle font tracking or casting the configuration label?

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to set the text/label font properties in my `ButtonStyle` when using the simple Button constructor with a `StringProtocol`, not passing in a full view, but the configuration label in the `makeBody` function won't allow it. I get why - `makeBody` returns `some View` which doesn't have the `tracking` and `textCase` modifiers I'd like to use.

Is there a way to cast the configuration label to be a `Text` view or some way for me to put the additional font modifiers (tracking & textCase) directly into my `ButtonStyle` so I don't have to pass in a `Text` view with additional modifiers?

```swift
// The Text properties I'd like to modify which are not available
// on the configuration label, so I've added them to this Text extension
extension Text {
  func buttonText() -> some View {
    self.tracking(2.0).textCase(.uppercase)
  }
}

// What I would like...
Button("Some Text") {
  // Some action
}
  .buttonStyle(BrandedButton())

// What I currently have to do
Button(action: {}, label: {
  Text("Some Text")
    .buttonText()
})
  .buttonStyle(BrandedButton())
```

`BrandedButton` is my `ButtonStyle`. My obvious concern is that this duplication - having to add the `.buttonText()` modifier everywhere - is easily overlooked and can result in some mismatched styling of buttons. `.font` is a valid modifier for `configuration.label`, but the others are not.